# Troubler with Code Composer Studio using C

Tags: c, settings

I'm new to using code composer studio, and I need to use a MSP-EX430F5529P board to run a simple function, but it gives me a negative result when it should be positive. I'm pretty sure its an error in the properties of the project, but I have no clue what the correct settings are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <msp430.h> 


/**
 * hello.c
 */


long CalcPower(int base, int exponent){
    long result = 1;
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i<exponent; i++){
        result *= base;
    }
    return result;
}






int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // stop watchdog timer
    int a = 13;
    int p = 5;
    
    long b = CalcPower(a, p);

    printf("%d to the power of %d is %d\n", a, p, b);
    
    return 0;
}
```

"13 to the power of 5 is -21923" is what I am getting, but I need "13 to the power of 5 is 371293"

Comment: Does your compiler _understand_ `long`? `371293` mod `65536` is `43613` which is exactly `21923` short of reach the overflow value (65536) again...

Comment: Wouldn't stdio.h handle that?

Comment: @Fe203 lets say it doesn't. What are my next steps? use double or try and convert it into hex?

Comment: I don't know your compiler, but the first attempt might be using `%ld` instead of `%d` to print the `long` value...

Comment: `%d` expects an `int`, not a `long`.  Change it to `%ld` when printing `b`, which is a `long`.  It's basically a typo.

Comment: @Tom Karzes that may be the issue, but my system doesn't support ld

Comment: "_my system doesn't support ld_" Time to roll up your sleeves to write a "long to ascii string" conversion function (missing from your `printf()`?!?!), and then print the string that is produced...

Comment: @AjGraham I find that hard to believe.  `%ld` is a standard `printf` format specifier.  It is required for `long`.  If your system doesn't support `%ld`, then it doesn't support the `long` data type.  Did you actually try using `%ld` in your format string?  Are you *certain*?  If it doesn't support it, then it doesn't support the C language.  That's `%`, the lowercase letter `l`, and the lowercase letter `d`.  Make sure it's `l` and not `1`.

Comment: line 32: error #2632: Modifiers are not allowed in printf_support=minimal mode

Comment: printf("%d to the power of %d is %ld\n", a, p, b);

Comment: Welcome to SO. As CCS normally allows to use different compilers, you should extent your question to include the used compiler. As you mentioned, the compiler and library (or your configuration) use something they call "minimal mode". That clearly sounds like some features are disabled to get smaller binaries. Can you change that to some "full mode" or similar?

Comment: Maybe change to `nofloat` mode? https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau132y/slau132y.pdf?ts=1692806747247

Comment: Fixed @Gerhardh. Printf/Scanf was set to nofloat and it needed to be on full. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm? The error message said it was `minimal`. You only want integer types, no floating point types. Are you sure, `nofloat` isn't enough?

Comment: I found the settings. If people want it I can post the pdf, but the answer I posted gave me the correct outcome for the 1 example I had to run.

Answer (score 1):

[printf set to nofloat needed to be on full. Thanks to Gerhardh. Hit the nail on the head.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJjNn.png)

since i got to add more according to stack overflow, not setting it to full makes it so you can only use ints and nothing else. Because of this, i was having an overflow error where it went past what it was supposed to and became negative. aka an overflow error because the settings were incorrect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

MSP-EX430F5529P is 16bit RISC MCU. The TI compiler for this MCU supports 16bit size for long integer and remember it is signed long integer, so range is -32768 to 32767.

So when you do 13x13x13x13x13 = 371293, "result" variable overflows after 32767 and not just once but 12 times. So after 12 times it gives you 371293-(32768*12) = -21923.

Better be careful with data types, otherwise sometimes it can become a classic case of run time error.